# state as an argument to access an object?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

(i'm new to react btw)
So i'm trying to make a code that:

1. Reads the value of two select boxes and an input
2. Uses the value of the selects to read a Javascript object
3. Multiplies the value of the input by the value from the object.

This is what I've got to so far:

```
const valores = {
  longitud: {
    metros: {
      val: 1,
    },
    centímetros: {
      val: 0.01,
    },
  fuerza: {
    newtons: {
      val: 1,
    },
    dina: {
      val: 0.0000001,
    },
  }
}
const [tipo, setTipo] = useState("longitud")
  const [uIn, setUIn] = useState("metros")
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0)
  const unidades = {
    longitud: [
      "metros",
      "centímetros",
    ],
    fuerza: ["newtons", "dinas"],
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        id="tipoMedida"
        value={tipo}
        onChange={e => setTipo(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="longitud">Longitud</option>
        <option value="fuerza">Fuerza</option>
        
      </select>

      <input type="number" id="valor" value={val}
        onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}/>

      <select id="unidadOrigen" value={uIn}
        onChange={e => setUIn(e.target.value)}>
        {unidades[tipo].map(u => {
          return <option value={u}>{u}</option>
        })}
      </select>
```

This part works fine. However, I'm not sure how to do the next one. I want to show a text that shows the result, for which i did this
`<div id="resultado">El resultado es {val*valores[tipo[uIn[val]]]}</div>`but it shows nothing, and `{val*valores[tipo[uIn.val]]}` says uIn is undefined.  Is something wrong with my code, and if not how could I achive that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are accessing the objects is causing the issue.

The correct way would be to do

```js
const result = val * valores[tipo][uIn].val;
console.log(result);
```

The final code would look like this.

*Please note that I made some changes in the **onChange** handler for the first select as it was leading to a bug. The default of `uIn` needed to be changed when `tipo` was modified*

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const valores = {
    longitud: {
      metros: {
        val: 1
      },
      centímetros: {
        val: 0.01
      }
    },
    fuerza: {
      newtons: {
        val: 1
      },
      dinas: {
        val: 0.0000001
      }
    }
  };
  const [tipo, setTipo] = useState("longitud");
  const [uIn, setUIn] = useState("metros");
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  const unidades = {
    longitud: ["metros", "centímetros"],
    fuerza: ["newtons", "dinas"]
  };

  const result = val * valores[tipo][uIn].val;

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        id="tipoMedida"
        value={tipo}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setTipo(e.target.value);
          setUIn(unidades[e.target.value][0]);
        }}
      >
        <option value="longitud">Longitud</option>
        <option value="fuerza">Fuerza</option>
      </select>

      <input
        type="number"
        id="valor"
        value={val}
        onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
      />

      <select
        id="unidadOrigen"
        value={uIn}
        onChange={(e) => setUIn(e.target.value)}
      >
        {unidades[tipo].map((u) => {
          return (
            <option key={u} value={u}>
              {u}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>

      <div id="resultado">El resultado es {result}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Tip: Instead of hardcoding values in the `unidades` variable, you can use the javascript method `Object.keys()` to generate the options dynamically. That way, when new options are added, you don't need to make a lot of changes in a lot of places.